# Freeze of app during collectionViewCell size calculation & reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uicollectionview

I'm in a bit of a predicament.
Here is the problem I'm currently facing.

I have a collectionView containing dynamic sized cell.
This collectionview is fed data through a paginated API.
Each time I reload new data my app freezes during the reloadData process and calculation of the cell’s sizes.

To calculate the good size for each cell depending on its content I do the following:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
layoutcollectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,
sizeForItemAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let size: CGFloat
    if traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        size = floor((collectionView.frame.size.width))
    } else {
       size = floor(UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape ? 
        (collectionView.frame.size.width - 5.0 * Style.Size.Margin) / 4.0 : 
        (collectionView.frame.size.width - 4.0 * Style.Size.Margin) / 3.0)
    }

    // Instantiate my nib cell
    let cell = MyCell()

    // Set the width constraint for the cell
    cell.widthConstraint?.constant = size

    let item = dataSource[indexpath.row]
    // Apply content to the cell
    cell.update(item)

    // Calculate the appropriate height for cell
    let sizeCell = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
    return sizeCell
 }
```

As you can see, I set a width constraint on the cell and apply the following calculation:

`cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)`

The problem is that this process freezes the app for quite some time when I launch a reloadData of the collectionView making the UI scrolling experience unpleasant and choppy.
I don’t seem to find a good way to have a smooth scroll for my collectionView. I really hope there is a way to better the user experience.

You will find following the process of adding the data to my data source in pseudo code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row >= dataSource.count - 10, !fetchingMoredata, 
      !dataSource.isEmpty {
        fetchingMoreData = true
        fetchMoreData()
    }
}

func fetchMoreData () {

    API.callToGetMoreData() { newdata
      self.dataSource += newdata
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let contentOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.collectionView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
        self.fetchingMoreData = false
    }
  }
}
```

If you have any idea why my implementation causes these freezes during my reloadData / size calculation or how to better the entire process you’re help, or advice would be very welcome.

If you’re missing any information, I’d be more than glad to help with more precisions.

Thanks in advance.

Martin

Comment: Why you update your cell in `layoutcollectionViewLayout`? Whats wrong with `cellForItemAt`?

Comment: Are you tried without a `dispatchQueue`?

Comment: @canister_exister he is just using that cell to calculate the size and that computation could be heavy depending on the cell's view hierarchy. You can try to cache the size as it looks like all the cells have the same size, so the computation will happen just once.

Comment: @FabioFelici as you can see he is not just calculating size, he call update for cell `let item = dataSource[indexpath.row]
    // Apply content to the cell
    cell.update(item)`

Comment: @canister_exister yeah but I guess inside that `update` he is assigning text to labels in order to understand the text height.

Comment: @FabioFelici which is wrong. He don't need to set cell constraint at all in this method, because this function already return size for cell, and update cell data either.

Comment: @FabioFelici First of all thank you for the interest in this post. Fabio you are right with this assumption that I’m feeding data to a cell to be able to calculate the intrinsic size of it’s entire display. The problem is that not one of my cells has the same data meaning not one of my cell has the same height. This is why I calculate the size to display for each indexPath in the function layoutcollectionViewLayout. I would be curious to know how you guys implement a collection view with complexe cells that doesn’t freeze during reloadData.

Comment: https://parveenkaler.com/posts/self-sizing-uicollectionviewcell-swift